+/- when solving $y' + \frac{3}{x}\times y = 3x - 2$ via Integrating Factor Method
According to the internet, the solution to $y' + \frac{3}{x}y = 3x - 2$ is $y = \frac{3x^2}{5} - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{C}{x^3}$.
However, when I use the Integrating Factor Method, I get $\mu = e^{\int \frac{3}{x}dx} = |x^3|$, which is just $x^3$ for $x \geq 0$ and is $-x^3$ for $x < 0$. This leads me to having my final answer as $y = \pm \left(\frac{3x^2}{5} - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{C}{x^3}\right)$. Is there any particular reason the online problem solvers are omitting the $\pm$?

A function $\exp$(something) is always positive...

Check and you will see that only one of your solutions satisfies the original equation.

Cheers all, both are great comments. Sometimes you work on challenging math for so long that you forgot to remember the basics!

Since $e^{ln|x^3|} > 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x\neq 0$, then $e^{ln|x^3|} = x^3$ (no $\pm$ needed).
Even if you thought the answer was $\pm$, you could easily verify that only the positive version satisfied the given ODE.

looks at paper B-bu-but sir... you answered your own question....(jokes aside, $x^{k}>0$ is true $\forall x>0,k \in \mathbb{R}$  if I am not wrong)

I too found it strange that Stack Exchange has a button that says "answer your own question" but alas, here we are.
